# How to stretch buttons to fit GridView

Tags: android, xml, view

I have activity with three GrindViews. I fill these views with custom SimpleCursorAdapters. In each cell is button which I need to be stretched into that cell of GrindView. And also I need that there will be no free space between that GrindViews. I already try to set padding/margin with no effect. Here are the XMLs:

MainView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<GridView android:id="@+id/gridview1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:numColumns="5"
    android:gravity="center" />

<GridView android:id="@+id/gridview2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:numColumns="5"
    android:gravity="center" />

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview3" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:numColumns="4"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Cell:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="1dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="1dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/textButton" />
```

Screenshot:
[Current Status](http://img706.imageshack.us/i/devicedm.png/)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Darn, I was hoping to learn about some sexy new GrindView!  I'm not sure I understand what it is you want to do.  Is it possible that the solution is simply to remove android:padding="1dip" from the LinearLayout and Button of your Cell?

Comment: Maybe this screenshot will be better [link](http://img593.imageshack.us/i/devicelo.png/). I just want to stretch buttons to cover whole orange area. So there will be almost no black background around them. And this happens if I remove padding from button (cell) - [link](http://img64.imageshack.us/i/devicefb.png/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to set your own drawable image for your buttons, and not use the standard system image.  Unless I'm mistaken, the standard MDPI image for buttons has a built in transparent border of 3 pixels on the horizontal sides, 1 pixel on the top side, and 4 pixels on the bottom side.  So, even if this button image were fully expanded to 100% fill a grid cell, it would still include this transparent border, and thus not appear to fully fill the cell.  (This is based on the assumption that the default button image is btn_default_normal.9.png.)

Instead of using Buttons, take a look at [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html), which allows you to set your own image.  Or, to use the regular [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html), you may need to set the button's background image with a state list drawable.  Take a look at the "Button style" section for more information.

--

However, I do see now in the docs, "Explicitly setting a padding value will override the corresponding padding found in the background."  I see you mentioned you tried setting the padding, but did you try setting the padding to zero?

Comment: You're right. Setting my own background image for button helps and now whole area is covered. Thank you for answer! fyi - setting the padding to zero didn't help.